# EmberJS is not automatically showing attributes from context object in view

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

After following the "Outlets" guide on Emberjs.com (http://emberjs.com/guides/outlets/) I am unable to show the title and body of the post in the Post (child/singular) template. Have any of you run into this? Here's the rundown:

```
# PostsTemplate
{{#each post in controller}}
  <h1><a {{action showPost post href=true}}>{{post.title}}</a></h1>
  <div>{{post.body}}</div>   <------ title and body show up correctly here
{{/each}}

# PostTemplate
<h1>{{title}}</h1>  <---- but title and body are EMPTY here  
<div class="body">
  {{body}}
</div>
{{outlet}}

# Router
App.Router = Ember.Router.extend({
  root: Ember.Route.extend({
    index: Ember.Route.extend({
      route: '/',
      redirectsTo: 'posts'
    }),
    posts: Ember.Route.extend({
      route: '/posts',
      showPost: Ember.Route.transitionTo('post'),
      connectOutlets: function(router) {
        router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('posts', App.Post.find());
      }
    }),
    post: Ember.Route.extend({
      route: '/posts/:post_id',
      connectOutlets: function(router, post) {
        console.log(post);    <------------------ This tells me the post has the write attributes.
        router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('post', post); #This post does not show up in PostTemplate above!
      }
     })
 });
```

When I run console.log(post), and inspect the post, I see that I have something like the following:

```
Class = {
 id: "1",
 _data:
  { 
    attributes:
    {
      body: "a",
      title: "a" 
    }
  },
  title: null,
  body: null
 }
```

Anyone have any ideas as to why I'm not seeing the title or body attributes show up in the view?

p.s. the Post model is an Ember data model that correctly retrieves the Post with id 1 from a Rails application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can use {{content.title}} and {{content.body}} since your Post model should be set to the content of the postController.  An easy way to debug this within the view is to put {{content}} in the view which will render the type of model that the item is (such as App.Post).

Comment: Nice! I'll give that a try and report back!